# How to define constants in Visual C# like #define in C?

Tags: c#, constants

In C you can define constants like this

```
#define NUMBER 9
```

so that wherever NUMBER appears in the program it is replaced with 9.  But Visual C# doesn't do this.  How is it done?

Comment: A better use-case for C#: `#define SOMETYPE typeof(MyClass)`, for use to keep things D.R.Y. when calling something like `SomeMethod<SOMETYPE>()`.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson I think you can do the same thing as the accepted answer by using Type rather than int.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
public const int NUMBER = 9;
```

You'd need to put it in a class somewhere, and the usage would be `ClassName.NUMBER`

Comment: If it isn't a macro, why have the hideous all caps naming? Might as well give the constant a meaningful name and consider it valid a constant instead of pretending that it is a macro.

Comment: Is there a way too define programwide variables wich don't need to have to be called using a class?

Comment: @MrUniverse I agree with you, I hate when I see `Constants.SECURITY_KEY`. I prefer `Constants.SecurityKey`.

Comment: @MrUniverse It is up to your team to decide what standard to use when naming variables. Some tools enforce that you use uppercase for constants (we have that check in our settings for our resharper plugin), but you can turn off that rule if you wish to not use that standard.

Comment: I am wondering, does this use RAM? The reason I wanted to use #define like in C, is to save on performance while allowing easy changing of variables and somewhat shorter typed code.

Comment: What if I want an alternative to `#DEFINE LL Long Long`?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him You can use `using` at the top of each file to create an alias for a class. `using LL = System.Int64;` at the top of a file will make `LL` an alias for `long` for example.

Answer (score 20):

```
static class Constants
{
    public const int MIN_LENGTH = 5;
    public const int MIN_WIDTH  = 5; 
    public const int MIN_HEIGHT = 6;
}

// elsewhere
public CBox()
{
    length = Constants.MIN_LENGTH; 
    width  = Constants.MIN_WIDTH; 
    height = Constants.MIN_HEIGHT;  
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: If it isn't a macro, why have the hideous all caps naming? Might as well give them meaningful names and consider them valid constants instead of pretending that they are macros.

Answer (score 16):

You can't do this in C#. Use a [`const int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 15):

Check [How to: Define Constants in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397677.aspx) on MSDN:

> In C# the `#define` preprocessor
>   directive cannot be used to define
>   constants in the way that is typically
>   used in C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

in c language: **`#define`** (e.g.  #define counter 100)

in assembly language: **equ** (e.g.  counter equ 100)

in c# language: [according to msdn refrence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx):
You use `#define` to define a symbol. When you use the symbol as the expression that's passed to the `#if` directive, the expression will evaluate to true, as the following example shows:

`# define DEBUG`

The `#define` directive cannot be used to declare constant values as is typically done in C and C++. Constants in C# are best defined as static members of a class or struct. If you have several such constants, consider creating a separate "Constants" class to hold them.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, per MSDN library, we have the "const" keyword that does the work of the "#define" keyword in other languages.

"...when the compiler encounters a constant identifier in C# source code (for example, months), it substitutes the literal value directly into the intermediate language (IL) code that it produces."
( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx )

Initialize constants at time of declaration since there is no changing them.

```
public const int cMonths = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the "Visual C#"? There is no such thing. Just C#, or .NET C# :)

Also, Python's convention for constants `CONSTANT_NAME` is not very common in C#. We are usually using **CamelCase** according to MSDN standards, e.g. `public const string ExtractedMagicString = "vs2019";`

> Source: [Defining constants in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-constants)